# Inter-rater reliability of multiple raters responding to (some subset of) multiple questions (in R)

Tags: r, data-cleaning, melt, reformatting, cohen-kappa

I have data from 5 raters who provided ratings of transcripts by answering up to a dozen questions about each transcript. Each question used a different rating system (e.g., yes vs. no, 1-7, or this vs. that vs. indeterminant).

A toy example of the data can be made with this code.

```
data.table(Rater = c("A","B","C","D","E"),
           Content = c("I","I","I","I","I","II","II","II","II","II"),
           Question1 = c("Yes","No","Yes","No","NA"),
           Question2 = c("1","3","5","7","NA"),
           Question3 = c("This","That","Indeterminate","This","Indeterminate"))
```

Which produces what is below:

```
    Rater Content Question1 Question2     Question3
 1:     A       I       Yes         1          This
 2:     B       I        No         3          That
 3:     C       I       Yes         5 Indeterminate
 4:     D       I        No         7          This
 5:     E       I        NA        NA Indeterminate
 6:     A      II       Yes         1          This
 7:     B      II        No         3          That
 8:     C      II       Yes         5 Indeterminate
 9:     D      II        No         7          This
10:     E      II        NA        NA Indeterminate
```

**I need to compute the interrater reliability for the raters.**

The `kappa2` function of the `irr` package would need data to be in long format (if I understand correctly)—something like:

```
Rater                   A     B  ...     E
Question1_Content_I   Yes    No  ...    NA    
Question2_Content_I     1     3  ...    NA     
Question3_Content_I  This  That  ...  Ind.
Question1_Content_II  Yes    No  ...  Ind. 
...
```

1. **How can I (re)format the data to compute IRR scores** (with kappa2 or another function)**?** (Would `melt` do the trick?)
2. **What functions would compute IRR scores for each kind of question/rating?** (And, if applicable, for data (re)format(ing) would they require?)
3. **Must there be separate IRR scores for each question/rating or is there a way to compute an overall IRR (across the questions)?**
4. **What needs to be done to accomodate the fact that some raters didn't respond to every question?**

Thank you for your advice!

Comment: I have made a new post that is more similar to the dataset I am working with at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73912754/how-to-clean-redundancies-and-missings-in-rater-dataset-and-then-compute-reliabi