# How to clean redundancies and missings in rater dataset and then compute reliability (e.g., Cohen's kappa) using R?

Tags: r, reshape, correlation, data-cleaning, rating

I've nearly 10,000 rows of numeric and text ratings about various items from up to 5 raters. I need to

**1. Clean the data (particularly redundancies and empty ratings)**

**2. Compute inter-rater <strike>reliability</strike>*agreement* (e.g., with Cohen's kappa or *r<sub>WG(J)</sub>*?)**

This code will make a reproducible toy example of the data:

```
ToyData <- data.table(Session_Item = c("A_I","B_I","C_I","D_I","E_I", "A_II","B_II","C_II","D_II","E_II"),
                      Rater1 = c("Yes","c('No', 'No')","3","5","1","Yes","No","3","5","7"),
                      Rater2 = c("c('Yes', 'Yes')","No","3","5","2","Yes","c('No', 'No')","3","5","7"),
                      Rater3 = c("Yes","No","3","5","1","NULL","NULL","NULL","NULL","NULL"),
                      Rater4 = c("NULL","NULL","NULL","NULL","NULL","Yes","No","3","5","6"))
```

That toy data looks like this.

```
    Session_Item        Rater1          Rater2 Rater3 Rater4
 1:          A_I           Yes c('Yes', 'Yes')    Yes   NULL
 2:          B_I c('No', 'No')              No     No   NULL
 3:          C_I             3               3      3   NULL
 4:          D_I             5               5      5   NULL
 5:          E_I             1               2      1   NULL
 6:         A_II           Yes             Yes   NULL    Yes
 7:         B_II            No   c('No', 'No')   NULL     No
 8:         C_II             3               3   NULL      3
 9:         D_II             5               5   NULL      5
10:         E_II             7               7   NULL      6
```

As you can see, there are

(I) cases in which one rater rated something more than once (e.g., "c('Yes', 'Yes')" or ""c('No', 'No')"). **How do I distill the common answer from the duplicates?**

(II) empty rating cells (e.g., "NULL"). **How can I ensure that those don't get counted as a rating when computing inter-rater <strike>reliability</strike>*agreement*?**

Other questions:

A. **Which method of computing <strike>reliability</strike>*agreement* would be most appropriate given the (i) different number of ratings per item and (ii) combination of both numeric and non-numeric ratings?**

B. **Will I need to change the format of these data? (If so, how?)**

Comment: Were the redundancies coded ```"c('Yes','Yes')"```, ```"Yes, Yes"``` or just ```"Yes Yes"```? It seems like the variables in your reprex are all characters. However, from the coding used, it seems they are a mixture of nominal data (character) and numeric data. For reliability analysis you need to define which kind of data you have at hand. The mixture of values within your variables is quite uncommon.

Comment: HI @GRowInG. The redundancies were coded just "Yes" or "No". However, when reshaping the data to inter-rater reliability analysis, raters' duplicate responses were combined into the list form c("Yes", "Yes") or c("No", "No).

Answer (score 0):

**Re: (I) Redundancies**

To clean out the redundancies in the data (which has many more variants of the redundancies than I showed in the toy example), I used `grepl` to search for strings that had a quote at the end (thus capturing all the lists of redundancies) and replaced it with just a single instance of the string. Example below:

```
ToyData$Rater1 <- ifelse(grepl(".*Yes\'.*", ToyData$Rater1), "Yes", ToyData$Rater1)
```

That replaced `c('Yes', 'Yes')` (and even more redundant cells like `c('Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes')` etc.) with just `Yes`.

So I did that for each rater and for each kind of redundancy (including turning the Nulls into `NA`)—not exactly an efficient solution, but a solution.

Now I have a clean dataset, but with plenty of NAs in most rows. And those NAs seem to be preventing me from using an interrater agreement function like `kappam.fleiss` or `kappam.light`.

So I still need a solution to **(II)** (which may mean that I still need answers to **A** and **B**).

**Re: II Interrater Agreement scores, ignoring NAs**

I ended up just using `kappam.fleiss` on pairs of raters by selecting the raters' columns. Example below:

```
kappam.fleiss(ToyData[,1:2])
kappam.fleiss(ToyData[,1,3])
kappam.fleiss(ToyData[,2:3])
...
```

Alas, `kappam.fleiss` seems to ignore all rows that contain even a single NA (which is many of my rows). So it may be better to either (a) use a different function that can handle NAs or (b) collapse the columns to minimize NAs/row (which may be justified for analyses of raters' overall *agreement*, but not for analyses of each rater).

I welcome more input, of course.